# SQL-запрос в Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Есть вот такой sql-запрос:

```
select CARMODULEHISTORY.[IdCar],ObjectList.Id [routeObjectId],DATEADD(hour,(datediff(hour, GETUTCDATE(), getdate())),DATEADD(s, CARMODULEHISTORY.EventTime, ''1970-01-01 00:00:00'')) [IntersectionTime],0 [IntersectionType],GETDATE()[ModifiedDate],CARMODULEHISTORY.EventTime [gmteventtime]
from [dbo].Wialon_Data CARMODULEHISTORY with(nolock)
left join [dbo].[Disp_ObjectList] ObjectList on .dbo.Dist_Between(CARMODULEHISTORY.[Lat],CARMODULEHISTORY.[Long],ObjectList.[Lat],ObjectList.[Long]) < ObjectList.[rad]
where CARMODULEHISTORY.id>%(last)s and ObjectList.Id is not null
```

Выдает две ошибки:

1. Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "1970". (102) (SQLExecDirectW)
2. Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "with". Если эта инструкция является обобщенным табличным выражением, предложением xmlnamespaces или предложением в контексте отслеживания изменений, предыдущую инструкцию необходимо завершить точкой с запятой.

Обе ошибки пропадают,если убрать строку `DATEADD(hour,(datediff(hour, GETUTCDATE(), getdate())),DATEADD(s, CARMODULEHISTORY.EventTime, ''1970-01-01 00:00:00'')) [IntersectionTime]`, но это всего лишь преобразование даты и оно работает если запрос выполнять в mssqlsrv. Как можно переделать для python?

Comment: Это скрипт к какой базе? MySQL?

Comment: нет, ms sql server

Comment: А через какой модуль работаете с базой? Добавьте код

Comment: Должны быть одинарные кавычки?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, просто форматирование кода кривое было, поправил.